# How to find cell control with coded UI

Tags: wpf-controls, coded-ui-tests

I am really struggling to find wpf cell control. I have tried to record mouse click on button into the cell. I am using Coded UI test builder. The hierarchy `(ListView (table) -> DataItem (row) -> cell -> Button)` and search properties looks ok for me. But the playback is failing.

As well I have tried to hand code it and still cannot find cell control.

```
        WpfTable table = UIMainWindow.UIModelListCustom.UIListViewTable;
        table.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Table");
        table.SearchProperties.Add("AutomationId", "ListView");
        table.SearchProperties.Add("ClassName", "Uia.ListView");
        table.DrawHighlight();
```

DrawHighlight() method finds my table and draws a highlight around it.

```
        WpfRow ControlRow = new WpfRow(table);
        ControlRow.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "DataItem");
        ControlRow.SearchProperties.Add("ClassName", "Uia.ListViewItem");
        ControlRow.SearchProperties.Add("Instance", "2");
        ControlRow.DrawHighlight();
```

DrawHighlight() method finds my row and draws a highlight around it.

```
        WpfCell cell = new WpfCell(ControlRow);
        cell.SearchProperties.Add("ClassName", "Uia.ContentPresenter");
        cell.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Cell");
        cell.SearchProperties.Add("ColumnIndex", "1");
        cell.DrawHighlight();
```

Now DrawHighlight() method doesn't finds my cell and exception is shown:

> 'System.ArgumentException: No row was specified as search container
>   for the control. To search for a cell control using 'ColumnIndex', you
>   must specify row as a container element or add 'RowIndex' to the
>   search property of the cell. Parameter name: SearchProperties'

So I added additional search properties:

```
        cell.SearchProperties.Add("RowIndex", "1");
```

After this I got new exception:

> 'System.ArgumentException: No table was specified as search container
>   for the control. To search for a row or cell control using
>   'ColumnIndex' or 'RowIndex' or both, you must specify table as a
>   container element. Parameter name: SearchProperties'

Before search properties I added this line. In this point I am really not sure is it ok.

```
        cell.Container = table;
```

After this it still cannot find cell control and exception appears:

> 'UITestControlNotFoundException: The playback failed to find the
>   control with the given search properties.

Additional Details:

```
TechnologyName:  'UIA'
FrameworkId:  'Wpf'
ClassName:  'Uia.ContentPresenter'
ControlType:  'Cell'
ColumnIndex:  '1'
RowIndex:  '1'
```

Search may have failed at 'ListView' Table as it may have virtualized children. If the control being searched is descendant of 'ListView' Table then including it as the parent container may solve the problem.'

As well I have tried to use different syntax for container:

```
        ControlRow.Container = table;   
        cell.Container = ControlRow;
```

Plus tried to define cell as:

```
        WpfCell cell = new WpfCell(table);
```

But I still don't got any luck. Could anyone please explain how to find search control for cell?

Answer (score 0):

> Search may have failed at 'ListView' Table as it may have virtualized children. If the control being searched is descendant of 'ListView' Table then including it as the parent container may solve the problem.'

I've come across this a few times when searching for controls in tabs. To solve it I compare the variable declaration for the control with the control's location in the UIMap. If the hierarchies are different I set the controls Container to match what's in the Map

Answer (score 0):

UITestControl WindowControlTillHandle - Is the Control which has WindowHandle
string TableAutomationIdProperty - is the Table ID property fetched using UIAVerify

You can find UIAVerify tool under following location in your system - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x64\UIAVerify"

```
    public static void ClickTableContentUIATable(UITestControl WindowControlTillHandle, string TableAutomationIdProperty, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
    {
        AutomationElement mainWindow = AutomationElement.FromHandle(WindowControlTillHandle.WindowHandle);

        Condition condition1 = new System.Windows.Automation.PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, TableAutomationIdProperty);
        Condition condition2 = new System.Windows.Automation.PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.LocalizedControlTypeProperty, "table");
        System.Windows.Automation.AndCondition andCondition = new System.Windows.Automation.AndCondition(new Condition[] { condition1, condition2 });
        AutomationElement gridContol = mainWindow.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, andCondition);
        AutomationElement dataPanel_UIA = gridContol.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new System.Windows.Automation.PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Data Panel"));

        UITestControl dataPanel = UITestControlFactory.FromNativeElement(dataPanel_UIA, "UIA");
        TreeWalker treeWalker = TreeWalker.ContentViewWalker;
        AutomationElement element = treeWalker.GetFirstChild(dataPanel_UIA);
        List<AutomationElement> tableRowCollection = new List<AutomationElement>();
        List<string[]> tableContent = new List<string[]>();
        Mouse.Click(UITestControlFactory.FromNativeElement(element, "UIA"));
        AutomationElement lastElement = treeWalker.GetLastChild(dataPanel_UIA);
        AutomationElement prevElement = null;
        do
        {
            prevElement = element;
            if (!tableRowCollection.Contains(element))
            {
                tableRowCollection.Add(element);
                if (tableRowCollection.Count - 1 == rowIndex)
                {
                    Mouse.Click(UITestControlFactory.FromNativeElement(element, "UIA").GetChildren()[columnIndex]);
                    return;
                }
            }
            if (element == treeWalker.GetLastChild(dataPanel_UIA))
            {
                Keyboard.SendKeys(dataPanel, "{PageDown}");
                element = treeWalker.GetFirstChild(dataPanel_UIA);
                continue;
            }
            element = treeWalker.GetNextSibling(prevElement);
        } while (prevElement != lastElement);


    }
```